# How to apply style to a single element of a class, while removing style from the previous element of the same class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

To be more specific, I'm trying to have a series of img tiles that when one is selected, it receives a border. When a different image tile is selected of the same class, it will receive the border, while the previous selected img will have it's border removed.

A good example would be similar to the first example on this website:
http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/

**IMPORTANT:** I am trying to ***avoid jQuery*** and find a pure Javascript solution. Nothing against jQuery, I'm just on a mission to avoid it with this project.

Here's my code...

**CSS:**

```
<style>
.tile {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
</style>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
function example ()
{
    var i;                                                       // Counter
    var tilecount = document.querySelectorAll( '.tile' ).length; // Number of elements of the "tile" class
    var tilearray = document.getElementsByClassName( 'tile' );   // All tile elements

    for ( i = 0; i < tilecount; i++ )
    {
        if ( tilearray[i].style.border == 'none' )
        {
            tilearray[i].style.border = '5px solid #2c2d2d';
        }

        else
        {
            tilearray[i].style.border = 'none';
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img onclick="example()" class="tile" src="http://i.imgur.com/jlQyrWk.jpg" /></td>
        <td><img onclick="example()" class="tile" src="http://i.imgur.com/H6qGF5Z.jpg" /></td>
        <td><img onclick="example()" class="tile" src="http://i.imgur.com/76hOij3.png" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Unfortunately, my code isn't working, and I thought I'd pick the brains of the experts here at Stack Overflow. Again, please no jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is at most 1 element selected at all time, there is no need to loop through all elements.

You can simply store inside a public variable the last object that was clicked.

Then when you click on a new element you already have the reference to the element that was selected earlier.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><img onclick="example(this)" class="tile" src="http://i.imgur.com/jlQyrWk.jpg" /></td>
<td><img onclick="example(this)" class="tile" src="http://i.imgur.com/H6qGF5Z.jpg" /></td>
<td><img onclick="example(this)" class="tile" src="http://i.imgur.com/76hOij3.png" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var lastSelectedItem;
function example(element) {
    if(lastSelectedItem)
        lastSelectedItem.style.border = "none";
    element.style.border = "1px solid black";
    lastSelectedItem = element;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u05e1gLv/

Comment: I love that it avoids the loop. Best answer yet.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add `this` reference when you call the function and in your function loop through the elements, remove their borders and add border to the one that is being clicked.

```js
function example(el) {
  var tilearray = document.getElementsByClassName("tile"); // All tile elements.
  for(i = 0; i < tilearray.length; i++) {
    tilearray[i].style.border = '';
  }
  el.style.border = "5px solid #2c2d2d"
}
```

```css
.tile {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img onclick="example(this)" class="tile" src="http://i.imgur.com/jlQyrWk.jpg" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img onclick="example(this)" class="tile" src="http://i.imgur.com/H6qGF5Z.jpg" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img onclick="example(this)" class="tile" src="http://i.imgur.com/76hOij3.png" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse a variable into the function, then use that to select the element.

Notice the buttons call the function with a 'select' variable, which is used to select the correct element.

Also, you don't need to declare the i variable before a for loop, that's what i = 0 inside the loop is for.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><img onclick="example(0)" class="tile" src="http://i.imgur.com/jlQyrWk.jpg" /></td>
<td><img onclick="example(1)" class="tile" src="http://i.imgur.com/H6qGF5Z.jpg" /></td>
<td><img onclick="example(2)" class="tile" src="http://i.imgur.com/76hOij3.png" /></td>
</tr>
</table>



function example(select) {    
var tilecount = document.querySelectorAll('.tile').length; // Number of elements of the "tile" class.
var tilearray = document.getElementsByClassName("tile"); // All tile elements.

for(i = 0; i < tilecount; i++) {        
    tilearray[i].style.border = "none";
}
 tilearray[select].style.border = "5px solid #2c2d2d";
```

}